# Perform postback from js in Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

These is my aspx, how i can perform from js?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="RetailReport._Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server" enableviewstate="false">
    <link href="layout/Images/logo.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
    <title>My Site</title>
</head>
<frameset border="0" rows="55, *" id="rowsFrameset" runat="server" enableviewstate="false">
    <frame name="header" src="Header.aspx" noresize="noresize" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
    <frame name="mainpanel" src="ChildForm/Home.htm" noresize="noresize" frameborder="0">
    <noframes>
        <p id="p1">
            Reporting System
        </p>
    </noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

I have tried :

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

but doesn't work.
this is the postback js call
__doPostBack('rowsFrameset', 'myAction');

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post that part of your JS code that is calling __doPostBack?

Comment: Based on your aspx source code, you do not have a form on your page. You can't submit a form if it isn't on your page. You need at least a <form runat="server"><!-- form content --></form> in your aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Erik. You'd want the   element somewhere in the code for a postback to occur.

I don't see any button or control to trigger of the postback.